# How to rewrite the Delete and Update methods based on new DataSet binding?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dataset

I have added a new column to my DataSet and after adding, visual  studio asked me if I want to rewrite my updating methods and I said yes. Now, My Delete method is broken and I can not use it like before. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amirhesam
You have to manually configure your Delete method like below
Table Adapter Properties -> Delete Command -> CommandText
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdZbY.png)

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot that is exactly what I was looking for, I didn't know where to configure my updating methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using source control then diffing to see what it changed the delete to imo. Should be trivial to manually fix whatever the VS autogen did to bollocks it up.